# TikZ & library babel - Private macro \my@macro unusable with the text of a node

Tags: macros, babel, tikzlibrary

Is there a way to fix the following incompatibility ? I can't use my private macro for the text of a node.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\my@macro[1]{%
    {\tiny$\substack{-\\#1}$}%
}


\newcommand\test[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0, 0) 
              -- node[draw] {\my@macro{#1}}
              (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test{PARIS}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure why it fails, but the obvious solution is to eliminate the `@` characters in the macro name.  They are not needed and their elimination fixes the problem.

Comment: I would prefer to keep my macro private. I know this obvious solution but if there is a way to avoid taht it would be better for me.

Comment: Also, your MWE requires `amsmath` for `\substack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REVISED SOLUTION**

Thanks to Ulrike, who suggested an alternative to my original solution.  I like hers better: avoid the catcode issue with the invocation `\csname my@macro\encsname`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\my@macro[1]{%
    {\tiny$\substack{-\\#1}$}%
}


\newcommand\test[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0, 0) 
              -- node[draw] {\csname my@macro\endcsname{#1}}
              (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\test{PARIS}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION**

Not sure why it is needed, but by placing a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` wrapper around the embedded invocation, it can be made to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\my@macro[1]{%
    {\tiny$\substack{-\\#1}$}%
}


\newcommand\test[1]{\makeatletter\testaux{#1}\makeatother}
\newcommand\testaux[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0, 0) 
              -- node[draw] {\my@macro{#1}}
              (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\test{PARIS}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer to do the way you do. The problem should surely comes from a change of catcode.

Comment: @projetmbc Yes, one can look at the original error and see it is catcode related.  Also, Leaving the document in `\makeatletter` mode also fixes the problem, but is not acceptable for other reasons.

Comment: I would use `node[draw] {\csname my@macro\endcsname{#1}}`, seems less trouble.

Comment: Thanks for this solution easy to use.